# DatePicker on Flutter: null value on getting date piked :

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

can't get the date picked from my datepicker though i didn't getting error on my code.

```
  Future selectDate() async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: new DateTime(2016),
        lastDate: new DateTime(2222));
    if (picked != null) setState(() => picked = datepicked);
    else{
      print(picked);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `context` in the datepicker method. Complete working code below:

```
body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('click'),
        onPressed: () {
          selectDate(context);
        }
        )
      ),


Future selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: new DateTime(2016),
        lastDate: new DateTime(2222));
    if (picked != null && picked!= selectedDate) {
      setState(() => selectedDate = picked);
      print(picked);
    }
    else{
      print(picked);
    }
  }
```

// 2020-02-21 00:00:00.000

Comment: yeah, that was good answer too.sorry, I've just panic. my code is working ,I just uninstall my application and restart the hot reload.(i didn't know what was happended lately) by the way, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: picked != null :The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.

You try:      if (picked!= selectedDate) { .....